# Azure SQL connect to Azure storage for selected network

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-security

I have created connectivity from Azure SQL to Azure storage .

1. Create master key
2. Created scoped CREDENTIAL
3. Created External data source

connecting azure storage when Azure storage when Azure firewall selected All networks . If I change Selected network (attached screen shot) then connectivity not working . Please note my IP address already whitelisted .

Any suggestion how I can enable firewall and access storage from Azure Sql

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the `selected networks` for Storage firewall, you need to use the IP address to the control the access from client.

This operation is same with Azure SQL database firewall.

Please could add the client IP and click the Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account:

[image]

HTH,

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I forgot to mentioned . I have already try it . Added client ip and added Allow trusted Microsoft service - This is not working         https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#exceptions   Also I tried RBAC to check if that works .

Comment: @Jack You're welcome and hope you are doing well.. A little strange that it should works in usual.  If you get any progresses, hope you can share with us.